# Eclipse Spring MVC template project and Maven dependences

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I have a problem using Eclipse STS suite for developing Spring MVC project with Maven. By default, Spring MVC template uses maven for building. It builds with maven (rmc on pom.xml -> Run As -> Maven install) but eclipse highligts all maven-managemented dependencies in red. (and mark them as an errors) I'm using m2eclipse for eclipse WTP.
Here is a screenshot:
http://rghost.ru/24803261

And here is my pom.xml file: http://pastebin.com/5EvNQvHe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no error marker in the pom.xml then is mostly only a refereshing problem.

(Make sure, that Maven support is enables for this project ("package explorer"/Project/Maven/Enable Dependency Management).

Then Try: right click on your project in the "package explorer", select `Maven/Update Project Configuration` to update the project configuration.

Comment: Where is it - "package explorer"/Project/Maven/Enable Dependency Management? I'm completely new to eclipse, just migrating here from NetBeans. Are you talking about Project -> Properties? But there is no tab for maven. And there is no menu item for maven when i rmc on my project.

Comment: "Package Explorer" is a view/tab containing a tree with the project structure. (Press Crtl+3, type package explorer, press enter -- and the package exporer opens if it is not open, else the package explorere view/tab get the focus). Then select YOUR PROJECT, press the right mouse button, and the select Maven/Update Project in the context menu